# Separar logradouro de endereço de uma string

Tags: java, string, swing

Na minha aplicação `JAVA`, em uma tela, eu tenho campos referentes ao endereço, eu tenho dois meios de cadastrar esse endereço, eu posso pegar automaticamente buscando pelo CEP a maioria das informações ou colocando tudo “manualmente”.

O problema, é que muitas vezes o CEP não vai te retornar um resultado, ou retorna apenas algumas informações, como é o caso do lugar onde eu moro (é um pequeno Distrito). Então, resolvi deixar a opção de colocar manualmente.

No Banco de dados, eu salvo separadamente Tipo e Nome do Logradouro.

Para ajudar a entender os campos: 
Campo **Tipo do logradouro** (`comboBox`): Avenida, Rua, Estrada e etc.

Campo **nome do Logradouro**: Paraná, Cruzeiro, Rio Grande do Sul e etc;

Buscando o CEP automaticamente ele vai preencher o campo referente ao nome do logradouro. Ele vai preencher o campo por exemplo com Avenida Paraná. Pegando automaticamente ele não distingue tipo de nome. Se salvar o os dados "pegos" de forma automática, quando for realizada a consulta, ele não vai setar nos campos referentes a cada conteúdo, exemplo: Avenida seta no combo e Paraná no `TextField` (nome do logradouro).

O que eu quero, é poder separar o tipo, do nome (pegar a avenida). 
O propósito de ter esse `comboBox` (tipo do logradouro), é para que quando a inclusão for “manual”, o usuário não comece a cadastrar o mesmo tipo de Logradouro de maneiras diferentes, como por exemplo: Avenida, Av., Avn, AVENIDA, avenida e etc.

Se houver uma maneira que possa atendar essas condições de maneira mais simples ou diferente, estou aceitando sugestões.

Eu tentei separar usando `split()`, porém ele não distingue a posição, talvez agregando expressão regulares seria possível ?

Obs: no exemplo simples que coloquei abaixo, não coloquei a opção de pegar automaticamente, já que o que preciso é saber como separar na ordem o conteúdo dentro da `string`.

Obs2: Se a pergunta ainda estiver "esquisita", eu removo.

Um Exemplo bem simples do que eu tentei seria:

```
package testeCombo;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainCombo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{   
    private final String logradouro[] = {"<Selecione>", "Avenida", "Rua", "Estrada"};

    private JComboBox cmb = new JComboBox();
    private JTextField tf = new JTextField();    
    JPanel painel = new JPanel();
    JPanel painelBotao = new JPanel();
    private final JButton incluir = new JButton("OK");
    private final JButton consultar = new JButton("CONSULTAR");         
    private String salvaBD = "";
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel();

    public MainCombo() 
    {     
        setTitle("Combo + Text");
        setSize(550, 150);
        setResizable(false);         

        cmb = new JComboBox(logradouro);
        tf = new JTextField();        
        tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 25));
        painel.add(cmb);
        painel.add(tf);   
        getContentPane().add("South", painelBotao);        
        painelBotao.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        adicionaBotao(incluir);
        adicionaBotao(consultar);
        painel.add(label);        
        painel.add(label2);        
        add(painel);     
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void acao()
    {
        cmb.getSelectedItem();
        tf.getText();        
        salvaBD = (cmb.getSelectedItem() + " " + tf.getText());
        label.setText(salvaBD);
        cmb.setSelectedIndex(0);
        tf.setText("");        
    }

    public void consultar()
    {
        separa();
    }

    public void separa()//separa para quando consultar, o logradouro ir para o combo e o nome do logradouro pro TextField
    {     
        /*
        String [] separa = salvaBD.split(" ");
        String separado = separa[0].split(" ")[1];              
        label2.setText(" " + separado); 
        */        
        String[] arrayValores = salvaBD.split(" ");
        label2.setText(" " + Arrays.toString(arrayValores)); 
        //cmb.setSelectedIndex(); //setar valor no textField quando consulta   
        //tf.setValor(salvaBD);  //setar valor no textField quando consulta    
        label.setText("");// so para limpar o outro label
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

        if (ae.getSource() == incluir) 
        {            
            acao();
        } 

        if (ae.getSource() == consultar) 
        {            
            consultar();
        } 
    }

    private void adicionaBotao(JButton botao) 
    {
        painelBotao.add(botao);
        botao.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> 
        { 
            MainCombo combo = new MainCombo();
            combo.setVisible(true);
        });        
    }

    class textF extends JTextField
    {
        public void setValor(Object valor) 
        {
            setText("" + valor);
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Está faltando um monte de logradouro, você sabe ne? Olha no site dos correios. http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/sistemas/buscacep/buscaCep.cfm

Comment: Outra coisa, a consulta você faz onde? Geralmente apis baseada no site dos correios retornam um json, com todos os campos do link acima separados. Sua consulta retorna uma string unica com tudo?

Comment: @diegofm ia ficar muita coisa todos, isso é um exemplo simples ! O que eu vi por esse link é pago (o dos correios). Eu estou usando esse aqui https://gitlab.com/parg/ViaCEP

Comment: Então é simples: pega o logradouro, da um split até o primeiro espaço, compara o tipo com todos da lista que populará o combo e depois seta no combo quando a comparação for verdadeira :)

Comment: @diegofm então, como eu faço pro split() pegar só a primeira posição? eu tentei de algumas formas ali no exemplo, porém não deu certo.

Comment: Veja: https://ideone.com/5tfgmF

Comment: @diegofm  No meu caso, para pegar dos campos, eu terei que fazer algo como isto : https://ideone.com/cp6ApT, eu eu acho para o textField esta certo, mais o combo ...

Comment: Você está complicando algo fácil. É só fazer um `combo.setSelectedItem(log)` antes do `break` do laço, e usar o array logradouro para popular o combo. Você comparará com a lista, e não com o combo. Combobox aceita receber um array como inicializador, nem precisa adicionar um por um, um simples `new ComboBox(logradouro)` já o preenche.

Comment: @diegofm deu quase certo, ele só não seta de volta com combo.setSelectedItem(log), acredito que é porque eu ainda uso addItem, pois new ComboBox(logradouro) não deu certo. combo.setSelectedItem(logradouro) tbm não dá.

Comment: @diegofm teoricamente o que tem em log e logradouro não é a msm coisa? não deveria setar no combo então ?

Comment: Eu acho que nossas linhas de raciocínio estão seguindo um trajeto completamente diferente. `logradouro` a qual me refiro é o array do seu código. log é apenas uma representação temporária de cada elemento desse array dentro do for. Vou tentar depois me basear no código da pergunta e no que te mostrei no ideone e responder com um exemplo de como eu acredito que irá funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for um padrão de todo endereço que você consultar(acredito que seja, as APIs baseadas nos correios geralmente são sempre assim), para separar o tipo de logradouro você pode usar o método [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), passando um espaço como separador. Depois, do array resultante, pegue o primeiro índice, ele será o tipo.

Uma vez com o tipo separado, basta comparar com os do seu array `logradouros` para selecionar a opção no `JComboBox`.

Baseando-se no seu exemplo, fiz alterações em 2 métodos apenas, para ilustrar:

```
public void consultar() {
    String retorno = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Consulta");
    separa(retorno);
}

public void separa(String retorno) {

    if (retorno != null) {
        retorno = retorno.trim();
        String logTipo = retorno.split(" ")[0];

        for (String log : logradouros) {
            if (log.equalsIgnoreCase(logTipo)) {
                cmb.setSelectedItem(log);
                break;
            }
        }
        label2.setText(retorno.substring(retorno.indexOf(" "), retorno.length()));
        cmb.setEnabled(false);

    }
}
```

Repare que utilizei `equalsIgnoreCase` para evitar comparações como "rua" e "Rua" retornem falso.

Com essas alterações, o código funciona desse jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na linha:

```
label2.setText(retorno.substring(retorno.indexOf(" "), retorno.length()));
```

estou separando o resto do logradouro sem o tipo, cortando a string de endereço do primeiro espaço logo após o tipo até o final. O `trim()` é pra remover espaços desnecessários no começo e no fim da string.

Comment: Ele me apresenta um erro, porém não faz a aplicação para de funcionar, então acho que não tem problema, mais, apenas por desencargo de consciência, seria por que ele sai da condição do for em algum momento? O erro é: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1960) (...)

Comment: @GustavoSantos indexOf retorna -1 se ele não encontrar o charsequence informado como parametro, no caso deste código, o espaço em branco. Cheque em qual tipo de endereço isso ocorre, se não tiver um espaço em branco como separado entre tipo e logradouro, nem o split vai funcionar.

Comment: apesar do erro ele continua a funcionar, o erro ocorre quando vou setar o nome do logradouro que já esta separado. campoNomeLogradouro.setText(retorno.substring(retorno.indexOf(" "), retorno.length()));

Comment: @GustavoSantos de qualquer forma, precisa ser resolvido. Se você não tem como garantir que o endereço chegue sempre no formato `tipo logradouro`(separado por um espaço), então essa linha deve ser removida e o mais facil nesse caso é preencher o campo com a string toda

Comment: tudo bem, ainda vou tentar resolver, no caso de não resolver, vou mudar a maneira de fazer como você esta sugerindo, Obrigado ! :)